# AWS Glue ETL replace NULL value with 0

Tags: etl, aws-glue, data-warehouse

I'm building a datawarehouse fact table with AWS Glue Visual ETL.
After joining with dim table to retrieve the surrogate key I have some records remaining without a link to the dim table, which must be mapped to the zero record (N/A, missing values).

So in the ETL job I want to replace NULL with 0 for some columns so it matches my zero record.

How is this achieved in Glue? The fillmissingvalues component doesn't match my needs since I cannot specify the replacement value.

In MS SSIS I would tackle this simple question with a derived column using REPLACENULL(SK_DATE,0) but Glue leaves me confused..

Thanks!

Looked into fillmissingvalues, customtransform maybe an option writing code?
Will write stored procedure if this cant be solved easily..

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with a Custom Transformation task in the Glue Visual editor.

The code to put in the custom transformation task:

```
# If not already imported to the job you will need this import 
from pyspark.sql import functions as SqlFuncs

# it gets a collections of dynamic frames, so in this case we assume only one is passed in and grabs the first 
df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()

# example get value from other column if the column value is null
df = df.withColumn(
    "column_with_null_values",
    SqlFuncs.when(
        df.column_with_null_values.isNull(),
        df.another_column_with_value,
    ).otherwise(SqlFuncs.col("column_with_null_values")),
)

# example set value to a static value (N/A) if the column value is null 
df = df.withColumn(
    "another_column_with_null_values",
    SqlFuncs.when(
        df.another_column_with_null_values.isNull(),
        SqlFuncs.lit("N/A"),
    ).otherwise(df.another_column_with_null_values),
)

# example where the column can have both null and "" as value     
df = df.withColumn(
    "column_with_null_and_empty_values",
    SqlFuncs.when(
        df.column_with_null_and_empty_values.isNull() | SqlFuncs.col("column_with_null_and_empty_values").like(""), SqlFuncs.lit("N/A")
    ).otherwise(df.column_with_null_and_empty_values),
)

# return the result from the task 
dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "df_dynamic")
return DynamicFrameCollection({"CustomTransform0": dynamicFrame}, glueContext)
```

Note that many if the task types that are in Glue do not support to receive a *DynamicFrameCollection*, so you would need to create a **SelectFromCollection** task between.